# How yield catches StopIteration exception?

Tags: python, yield, stopiteration

Why in the example function terminates:

```
def func(iterable):
    while True:
        val = next(iterable)
        yield val
```

but if I take off yield statement function will raise StopIteration exception?

**EDIT:** Sorry for misleading you guys. I know what generators are and how to use them. Of course when I said function terminates I didn't mean eager evaluation of function. I just implied that when I use function to produce generator:

```
gen = func(iterable)
```

in case of *func* it works and returns the same generator, but in case of func2:

```
def func2(iterable):
    while True:
        val = next(iterable)
```

it raises StopIteration instead of *None* return or infinite loop.

Let me be more specific. There is a function *[tee](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)* in **itertools** which is equivalent to:

```
def tee(iterable, n=2):
    it = iter(iterable)
    deques = [collections.deque() for i in range(n)]
    def gen(mydeque):
        while True:
            if not mydeque:             # when the local deque is empty
                newval = next(it)       # fetch a new value and
                for d in deques:        # load it to all the deques
                    d.append(newval)
            yield mydeque.popleft()
    return tuple(gen(d) for d in deques)
```

There is, in fact, some magic, because nested function *gen* has infinite loop without break statements. *gen* function terminates due to *StopIteration* exception when there is no items in *it*. But it terminates correctly (without raising exceptions), i.e. just stops loop. **So the question is**: where is *StopIteration* is handled?

Comment: How are you calling this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Note: This question (and the original part of my answer to it) are only really meaningful for Python versions prior to 3.7. The behavior that was asked about no longer happens in 3.7 and later, thanks to changes described in [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/). So this question and the original answer are only really useful as historical artifacts. After the PEP was accepted, I added an additional section at the bottom of the answer which is more relevant to modern versions of Python.**

---

To answer your question about where the `StopIteration` gets caught in the `gen` generator created inside of `itertools.tee`: it doesn't. It is up to the consumer of the `tee` results to catch the exception as they iterate.

First off, it's important to note that a generator function (which is any function with a `yield` statement in it, anywhere) is fundamentally different than a normal function. Instead of running the function's code when it is called, instead, you'll just get a `generator` object when you call the function. Only when you iterate over the generator will you run the code.

A generator function will never finish iterating without raising `StopIteration` (unless it raises some other exception instead). `StopIteration` is the signal from the generator that it is done, and it is not optional. If you reach a `return` statement or the end of the generator function's code without raising anything, Python will raise `StopIteration` for you!

This is different from regular functions, which return `None` if they reach the end without returning anything else. It ties in with the different ways that generators work, as I described above.

Here's an example generator function that will make it easy to see how `StopIteration` gets raised:

```
def simple_generator():
    yield "foo"
    yield "bar"
    # StopIteration will be raised here automatically
```

Here's what happens when you consume it:

```
>>> g = simple_generator()
>>> next(g)
'foo'
>>> next(g)
'bar'
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)
StopIteration
```

Calling `simple_generator` always returns a `generator` object immediately (without running any of the code in the function). Each call of `next` on the generator object runs the code until the next `yield` statement, and returns the yielded value. If there is no more to get, `StopIteration` is raised.

Now, normally you don't see `StopIteration` exceptions. The reason for this is that you usually consume generators inside `for` loops. A `for` statement will automatically call `next` over and over until `StopIteration` gets raised. It will catch and suppress the `StopIteration` exception for you, so you don't need to mess around with `try`/`except` blocks to deal with it.

A `for` loop like `for item in iterable: do_suff(item)` is almost exactly equivalent to this `while` loop (the only difference being that a real `for` doesn't need a temporary variable to hold the iterator):

```
iterator = iter(iterable)
try:
    while True:
        item = next(iterator)
        do_stuff(item)
except StopIteration:
    pass
finally:
    del iterator
```

The `gen` generator function you showed at the top is one exception. It uses the `StopIteration` exception produced by the iterator it is consuming as it's own signal that it is done being iterated on. That is, rather than catching the `StopIteration` and then breaking out of the loop, it simply lets the exception go uncaught (presumably to be caught by some higher level code).

Unrelated to the main question, there is one other thing I want to point out. In your code, you're calling `next` on an variable called `iterable`. If you take that name as documentation for what type of object you will get, this is not necessarily safe.

`next` is part of the `iterator` protocol, not the `iterable` (or `container`) protocol. It may work for some kinds of iterables (such as files and generators, as those types are their own iterators), but it will fail for others iterables, such as tuples and lists. The more correct approach is to call `iter` on your `iterable` value, then call `next` on the iterator you receive. (Or just use `for` loops, which call both `iter` and `next` for you at appropriate times!)

---

**I just found my own answer in a Google search for a related question, and I feel I should update to point out that the answer above is not true in modern Python versions.**

[PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) has made it an error to allow a `StopIteration` to bubble up uncaught from a generator function. If that happens, Python will turn it into a `RuntimeError` exception instead. This means that code like the examples in older versions of `itertools` that used a `StopIteration` to break out of a generator function needs to be modified. Usually you'll need to catch the exception with a `try`/`except` and then `return`.

Because this was a backwards incompatible change, it was phased in gradually. In Python 3.5, all code worked as before by default, but you could get the new behavior with `from __future__ import generator_stop`. In Python 3.6, unmodified code would still work, but it would give a warning. In Python 3.7 and later, the new behavior applies all the time.

Comment: So, StopIteration is consumed by function definition (or equivalently generator structure)? I just want to figure out if we use next outside of function body it will raise exception, but if we use inside function it will terminate normally.

Comment: @BranAlgue No, the function definition won't consume the exception. Just like any other exception, a `StopIteration` will go up the call stack until it is caught by an explicit `try`/`catch` block, or by the implicit one inside a `for` loop. I think the thing you're missing is that `StopIteration` isn't a problem within a generator function. You're expected to raise one when you have nothing left to yield. You can do that explicitly with `raise StopIteration()`, or implicitly by getting to the end of the function -- or you can let the `StopIteration` produced by a call to `next` go uncaught.

Comment: I understand that. I don't understand why `StopIteration` isn't a problem inside generator function. Is the claim that generator implicitly handles the exception correct?

Comment: @BranAlgue: It isn't a problem because `StopIteration` is the signal a generator uses to show it is done. If you're in a generator function and you're manually iterating over an iterator using `next`, you'll usually be done when the iterator is exhausted. So rather than raising your own `StopIteration` exception you can simply let the one raised by `next` bubble up. There are some counterexamples, where you want to yield a final value or where you need to do some special clean up before ending, and in those cases you'll need to catch the `StopIteration`. But that is not very common.

Answer (score 9):

When a function contains `yield`, calling it does not actually execute anything, it merely creates a generator object. Only iterating over this object will execute the code. So my guess is that you're merely calling the function, which means the function doesn't raise `StopIteration` because *it is never being executed.*

Given your function, and an iterable:

```
def func(iterable):
    while True:
        val = next(iterable)
        yield val

iterable = iter([1, 2, 3])
```

This is the wrong way to call it:

```
func(iterable)
```

This is the right way:

```
for item in func(iterable):
    # do something with item
```

You could also store the generator in a variable and call `next()` on it (or iterate over it in some other way):

```
gen = func(iterable)
print(next(gen))   # prints 1
print(next(gen))   # prints 2
print(next(gen))   # prints 3
print(next(gen))   # StopIteration
```

By the way, a better way to write your function is as follows:

```
def func(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item
```

Or in Python 3.3 and later:

```
def func(iterable):
    yield from iter(iterable)
```

Of course, real generators are rarely so trivial.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

Without the `yield`, you iterate over the entire `iterable` without stopping to do anything with `val`. The `while` loop does not catch the `StopIteration` exception. An equivalent `for` loop would be:

```
def func(iterable):
    for val in iterable:
        pass
```

which does catch the `StopIteration` and simply exit the loop and thus return from the function.

You can explicitly catch the exception:

```
def func(iterable):
    while True:
        try:
            val = next(iterable)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

`yield` doesn't catch the `StopIteration`.  What `yield` does for your function is it causes it to become a generator function rather than a regular function.  Thus, the object returned from the function call is an iterable object (which calculates the next value when you ask it to with the `next` function (which gets called implicitly by a for loop)).  If you leave the `yield` statement out of it, then python executes the entire `while` loop right away which ends up exhausting the iterable (if it is finite) and raising `StopIteration` right when you call it.

consider:

```
x = func(x for x in [])
next(x)  #raises StopIteration
```

A `for` loop catches the exception -- That's how it knows when to stop calling `next` on the iterable you gave it.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Python 3.8, chunk as lazy generator

```
def split_to_chunk(size: int, iterable: Iterable) -> Iterable[Iterable]:
    source_iter = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        batch_iter = itertools.islice(source_iter, size)
        try:
            yield itertools.chain([next(batch_iter)], batch_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

Why handling StopInteration error: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/

```
def sample_gen() -> Iterable[int]:
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

for chunk in split_to_chunk(7, sample_gen()):
    pprint.pprint(list(chunk))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
............................
```