# Why do these generator expressions behave differently?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator-expression

These two code fragments differ only in the way the list is constructed. One uses `[]`, the other `list()`.

This one consumes the iterable and then raises a `StopIteration`:

```
>>> try:
...     iterable = iter(range(4))
...     while True:
...         print([next(iterable) for _ in range(2)])
... except StopIteration:
...     pass
...
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
```

This one consumes the iterable and loops forever printing the empty list.

```
>>> try:
...     iterable = iter(range(4))
...     while True:
...         print(list(next(iterable) for _ in range(2)))
... except StopIteration:
...     pass
...
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[]
[]
[]
etc.
```

What are the rules for this behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465313/how-yield-catches-stopiteration-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [PEP479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/), which says that

> The interaction of generators and StopIteration is currently somewhat
>   surprising, and can conceal obscure bugs. An unexpected exception
>   should not result in subtly altered behaviour, but should cause a
>   noisy and easily-debugged traceback. *Currently, StopIteration raised
>   accidentally inside a generator function will be interpreted as the
>   end of the iteration by the loop construct driving the generator*.

(emphasis mine)

So the constructor of `list` iterates over the passed generator expression until the `StopIteration` error is raised (by calling `next(iterable)` without the second argument). Another example:

```
def f():
    raise StopIteration # explicitly

def g():
    return 'g'

print(list(x() for x in (g, f, g))) # ['g']
print([x() for x in (g, f, g)]) # `f` raises StopIteration
```

On the other hand, * comprehensions work differently as they propagate the `StopIteration` to the caller.

---

The behaviour that the linked PEP proposed is as follows

> If a `StopIteration` is about to bubble out of a generator frame, it is
>   replaced with `RuntimeError`, which causes the `next()` call (which
>   invoked the generator) to fail, passing that exception out. From then
>   on it's just like any old exception.

Python 3.5 added the [`generator_stop` feature](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/__future__.html?highlight=generator_stop#module-__future__) which can be enabled using

```
from __future__ import generator_stop
```

This behaviour will be default in Python 3.7.

Comment: What are the rules for this behaviour? Why does ``[]`` not suppress the ``StopIteration``?

Comment: @Yurim I don't have any reference but I'm kind of sure that the exception doesn't survive out of the `list()` here. Internally it raises the exception and that causes the output to be *nothing* and then list picks up that *nothing* and makes an empty list. Because the list comprehension also looks for the very same exception inside `list()`