# About Python Generator

Tags: python, generator

How to understand the function `repeater2` and `repeater3`?

```
def repeater1(value):
    new = (yield value)

def repeater2(value):
    while True:
        new = (yield value)

def repeater3(value):
    while True:
        new = (yield value)
        if new is not None:value = new

r1,r2,r3 = repeater1(1),repeater2(2),repeater3(3)
r1.next() #1
r2.next() #2
r3.next() #3

r1.send(4) #StopIteration 
r2.send(4) #2
r2.next() #2
r3.send(4) #4
r3.next() #4
```

Comment: `new = field value ` is not valid python. there seems to be a bunch missing from this code.

Comment: Did you by accident confuse `field` and `yield`?

Comment: @KlausD. Ooo I'm so sorry,

Comment: @pvg bunch Added.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How yield catches StopIteration exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465313/how-yield-catches-stopiteration-exception)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose

Answer (score -2):

The variable `new` does not do anything in function `repeater2` (or `repeater1` for that matter). The function may be rewritten as:

```
def repeater2(value):
    while True:
        yield value
```

Also calling `r2.send()` is pointless because it does not do anything with the yield expression. Whatever you send to it, it will always return 2 because that was passed in during generator initialization.

`r3` yields the initial value of `3` for the first time and then whatever value is used in the `send` call for subsequent calls (as long as it is not None). The variable `new` is actually being used here.

It may make sense to rename these functions as `non_repeater`, `repeater` and `sendable_repeater`.