# In the answer provided except StopIteration hangs indefinitely and delete iterator is out of scope

Tags: generator, python-3.6

The previous answer that was posted here
[How yield catches StopIteration exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465313/how-yield-catches-stopiteration-exception)
and accepted shows the following:

```
iterator = iter(iterable)
try:
    while True:
        item = next(iterator)
        do_stuff(item)
except StopIteration:
    pass
finally:
    del iterator
```

The problem in Python 3.6.4 *pass* hangs indefinitely never closing out of the program cleanly.

*del* complains that the iterator is not defined when it is. My assumption is scope changes.

Any ideas how to exit cleanly when **StopIteration** is raised?

Answer (score 0):

Well I realized the loop expression must live inside the try statement only. I attempted to move the loop expression outside of the try catch block and it does hang indefinitely as well change scope when finally portion is executed.

I am sure there is a more formal answer that breaks down scope, exception and raise, etc. I now know there is only way to do this.