# mongo-conector not connecting with solr - Exception during collection dump

Tags: mongodb, solr, connector

I am connecting MongoDB with solr,

Following this document for integration:
https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr

**DB.Collection:** solr.wlslog

**D:\path to solr\bin>**

```
mongo-connector --unique-key=id -n solr.wlslog -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/wlslog -d solr_doc_manager
```

**I am getting below response and error:**

```
2020-06-15 12:15:45,744 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Starting mongo-connector version: 3.1.1
2020-06-15 12:15:45,744 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Python version: 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
2020-06-15 12:15:45,745 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-06-15 12:15:45,745 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - pymongo version: 3.10.1
2020-06-15 12:15:45,755 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Source MongoDB version: 4.2.2
2020-06-15 12:15:45,755 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Target DocManager: mongo_connector.doc_managers.solr_doc_manager version: 0.1.0
2020-06-15 12:15:45,787 [CRITICAL] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:713 - Exception during collection dump
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ancubate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py", line 292, in
batch = list(next(cleaned) for i in range(self.chunk_size))
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ancubate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py", line 668, in do_dump
upsert_all(dm)
File "C:\Users\ancubate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py", line 651, in upsert_all
dm.bulk_upsert(docs_to_dump(from_coll), mapped_ns, long_ts)
File "C:\Users\ancubate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mongo_connector\util.py", line 33, in wrapped
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ancubate\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py", line 292, in bulk_upsert
batch = list(next(cleaned) for i in range(self.chunk_size))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
2020-06-15 12:15:45,801 [ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:723 - OplogThread: Failed during dump collection cannot recover! Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset='rs0'), 'local'), 'oplog.rs')
2020-06-15 12:15:46,782 [ERROR] mongo_connector.connector:408 - MongoConnector: OplogThread <OplogThread(Thread-2, started 4936)> unexpectedly stopped! Shutting down
```

I searched over in GitHub issues of [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/issues) but not getting any solutions:

[Github-issue-870](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/issues/870)

[Github-issue-898](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/issues/898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the issue is resolved :)

My system OS is windows and i have installed mongodb in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\` (system's drive),

Before this mongo-connector connection, i have initiated replica set for mongodb using below command as per this [blog](https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr):

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath ../data/db --replSet rs0
```

## Problem:

The problem inside the `--dbpath ../data/db` directory, this directory was located in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data\db` this directory have all permissions but parent directory `C:\Program Files` have not all permission because its system's directory and protected directory.

**Actual Problem Was:** *(exception during collection dump)*

```
2020-06-15 12:15:45,787 [CRITICAL] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:713 - Exception during collection dump
```

## Solution:

I have just changed my `--dbpath` to another path that directory is outside of system's protected directory as below:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:/data/db --replSet rs0
```

After that i have executed below command for connection, as i posted in my question:

```
mongo-connector --unique-key=id -n solr.wlslog -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/wlslog -d solr_doc_manager
```

## Success mongo connector log result:

```
2020-06-17 12:08:52,292 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Starting mongo-connector version: 3.1.1
2020-06-17 12:08:52,292 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Python version: 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
2020-06-17 12:08:52,293 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-06-17 12:08:52,293 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - pymongo version: 3.10.1
2020-06-17 12:08:52,310 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Source MongoDB version: 4.2.2
2020-06-17 12:08:52,311 [ALWAYS] mongo_connector.connector:50 - Target DocManager: mongo_connector.doc_managers.solr_doc_manager version: 0.1.0
```

Hope this answer helpful for everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

in my case, this didn't solve the problem.
I'm using python 3.8, so for me it was actually due to https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#changes-in-python-behavior

> PEP 479 is enabled for all code in Python 3.7, meaning that
> StopIteration exceptions raised directly or indirectly in coroutines
> and generators are transformed into RuntimeError exceptions.
> (Contributed by Yury Selivanov in bpo-32670.)

reading [How yield catches StopIteration exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465313/how-yield-catches-stopiteration-exception) led me to think initially it was related to the yield doc statements but actually the problen was 2 lines calling next() in both line 292 and a few lines later in solr_doc_manager.py:

```
batch = list(next(cleaned) for i in range(self.chunk_size))
```

changed to:

```
        batch = []
        for i in range(self.chunk_size):
            for x in cleaned:
                batch.append(x)
```